# How to implement tabwidget functionality through listwidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I used tabwidget to achieve a function, but its default format is horizontal display, using it to achieve vertical display is too troublesome, and the characters can not be displayed horizontally, so I want to use listwidget to achieve the function of tabwidget,  select an item in the list and display the corresponding interface in this way, there will be no characters Problem with improperly formatted display.
par of my MusicPlayer.cpp:

```
MusicPlayer::MusicPlayer(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    MainList = new QListWidget;
    MainList->addItem(tr("1"));
    MainList->addItem(tr("2"));
    MainList->addItem(tr("3"));
    button = new QPushButton();
    tabwidget = new QTabWidget;
    QGridLayout* Layout = new QGridLayout;
    tabwidget->addTab(button,"first");
    tabwidget->addTab(MainList,"second");
    tabwidget->setTabPosition(QTabWidget::West);
    Layout->addWidget(tabwidget);
    setLayout(Layout);
    setWindowTitle(tr("Music Player"));
}
```

running it looks like:
[tabwidget mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6em4.png)

Comment: I'm surprised we cannot change the tabs orientation. You can of course do it with a `QListWidget` (and bind each item click with the corresponding page) or even use the [`QStackedWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstackedwidget.html#details) approach which would simplify the work (and for which you could use a `QListWidget`, a `QToolBar`, a `QComboBox` or whatever you'd want).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that I have implemented the related functions with listwidget and stackedwidget.

Comment: Using a QProxyStyle you can override the `sizeFromContents()` (to give enough space for the horizontal text and adjust the vertical one), and then `drawControl()` to temporarily ignore the text and do the default painting, then draw it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
  MusicPlayer::MusicPlayer(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    SideList = new QListWidget;
    SideList->addItem(tr("Like"));
    SideList->addItem(tr("Local"));
    SideList->addItem(tr("Recent"));

    MainList_1 = new QListWidget;
    MainList_1->addItem(tr("1"));
    MainList_1->addItem(tr("2"));
    MainList_1->addItem(tr("3"));

    MainList_2 = new QListWidget;
    MainList_2->addItem(tr("01"));
    MainList_2->addItem(tr("02"));
    MainList_2->addItem(tr("03"));
    stacked = new QStackedWidget;
    stacked->addWidget(MainList_1);
    stacked->addWidget(MainList_2);

    connect(SideList, SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(int)),
    stacked, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
    
    QGridLayout* Layout = new QGridLayout;
    Layout->addWidget(SideList,0,0);
    Layout->addWidget(stacked,0,1);
    setLayout(Layout);
    setWindowTitle(tr("Music Player"));

}
```